# Insert into table unique rows by postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, greenplum

I have some code stats in greenplum table A

```
| id  | file   | repo | lang | line |
-------------------------------------
| a   | /a.txt | r1   | txt  | 3    |
| a   | /b.c   | r1   | c    | 5    |
| b   | /x.java| r1   | java | 33   |
| c   | /f.cpp | r2   | c++  | 23   |
| a   | /a.txt | r3   | txt  | 3    |
| a   | /b.c   | r3   | c    | 5    |
```

but the last two rows code indicate this code is come form repo r1, because the commit id is same with first two rows.
I want to remove the duplicate rows, and insert result to table B:

```
| id  | file   | repo | lang | line |
-------------------------------------
| a   | /a.txt | r1   | txt  | 3    |
| a   | /b.c   | r1   | c    | 5    |
| b   | /x.java| r1   | java | 33   |
| c   | /f.cpp | r2   | c++  | 23   |
```

the row can be distinct by: id + file + repo

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NOT EXISTS to check that a duplicate does not exist:

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM t AS x
    WHERE x.id   = t.id
    AND   x.file = t.file
    AND   x.repo < t.repo
)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b2abd/3)

Comment: what does x.repo > t.repo  mean ?

Comment: You seem to have different repo for `a,/a.txt`: r1 and r3; this condition keeps r1 and discards r2. Seems to match the expected output.

Comment: There may be more than two repos, can this condition keep just one discard others?

Comment: This is what it should do... replace `>` with `<` to keep greatest or smallest repo and (compared as strings) discard all others. It assumes that repo is different if id and file of two rows are same.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregation would seem to do what you want:

```
select id, file, min(repo) as repo, lang, line
from t
group by id, file, lang, line;
```